# What can cause delays in callback from setTimeout(callback, 0)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

Does anyone know what can cause significant delays in the function passed to `setTimeout(func, 0)` being invoked?  I'm seeing delays of over 1.2 seconds between when `setTimeout(func, 0)` is executed and when `func` is actually invoked.

I only see this behavior with Chrome v52 (v51 did not have it).  So, it might be a Chrome issue but before I report it as a bug, I want to investigate it.

I unfortunately don't have a small case that repros it.  It occurs in an AngularJS app in response to a scroll event.  We handle a scroll event trigger by the mouse wheel, and as part of that, invoke `setTimeout(func, 0)` to do some follow up work.

Using the Chrome devtools, I can see that there is very little javascript run during this 1.2 second gap.  I am not blocking the thread.  In fact, I used console.profile and console.profileEnd to profile that specific 1.2 second grap.  It shows it is idle 99% of that time.

Looking at the timeline in the devtools, the only thing I do see firing during that time period is some handling of "Mouse Wheel" events.  There are a many of them (one every 5ish ms for about the first 1 second of the gap). Which is a little odd in itself because the mouse wheel isn't being scrolled during that time.  I do one flick of the Mac Magic Mouse 's virtual scroll wheel and we bang into the top of the scrollable area.  Event after we bang into the top, we keep getting the Mouse Wheel events.

Does anyone have any ideas?  Could a small stream of mouse wheel events that get executed very quickly delay the callback's invocation?  Is there any way to investigate why the timeout callback was invoked 1.2 seconds after its schedule time?

**Edit**: Added image of timeline depicting show callback of setTimeout.

[image: Timeline of slow setTimeout]

Comment: You will certainly need a reproducible example to report it as a bug, so please, don't hesitate to post it.

Comment: `setTimeout(func, 0)` puts the function on the queue and schedules it to be called next event loop comes around or the next "tick", in other words. Since the browser only uses a single thread for the UI, it could be an issue with something hogging it. The mouse wheel events _could_ be related, but I don't think there is a definite way to tell without examining what and why they are doing.

Comment: I've added an image showing the timeline when this happens.  The console is logging when the `setTimeout` method is invoked and when the callback is executed.  In this example, it takes over 1.4 seconds.  The summary graph indicates we are idle for the majority of the time.  Can it really be someone is hogging the thread?

Comment: Does the window have focus? Chrome starves windows that don't have focus.  Have you got rid of the mouse wheel events to see if that alleviates the problem?

Comment: The window does have focus the entire time.  I'm going to see if I can get rid of the mouse wheel events using debouncing as described below.  Unfortunately, that means modifying a third-party component so it'll take a little effort on my part.  I'll follow up hopefully tomorrow with the results.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout(..., 0)` puts an event in the event queue. But it does not get priority over other events which were already put in the queue. Certainly when you handle scroll events, you will get into situations where many scroll events are being put in the queue, while the scroll event handler code is still running that is handling a previous scroll event.

So, in fact you'll easily get into delays when handling scroll events. When your call stack is empty, i.e. when the currently running event handler finishes, the next event will be taken from the event queue. And even though there is a timeout-related event in that queue somewhere, it will not get a higher priority: all events have to wait their turn.

For example, if there are already 10 scroll events in the queue, they will all have to be processed, and when the mouse is still scrolling, the the problem is only to get worse, as it can add more of those to the queue, and at a higher rate that your code can process them.

One way to resolve this, is to make your scroll event handler as light as possible, and do the heavy stuff asynchronously. If the handler detects that in a previous run something was already scheduled to run in that way, it could simply cancel that scheduled task, and replace it with a new version.

Sample code:

```
var task = -1;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    clearTimeout(task);
    task = setTimeout(function () {
        // all the (heavy) processing related to scrolling comes here.
    }, 0);
};
```

This `setTimeout` is not to be confused with the one from the question. But notice that when you have launched another `setTimeout`, it will be processed in order. The above code will just move the actual processing to the end of the queue. But if there are many more scroll events, they will each *remove* that timeout event from the queue, and put a new one at the *end* of the queue.

This will have as effect that you'll actually have fewer executions of the heavy part of the scroll handler code, which might have some negative effects on fluidity of some animation. But it will prevent *lagging*, and as a bonus, your other `setTimeout` event will get its turn sooner.

Comment: *"...one [scroll event] every 5ish ms for about the first 1 second of the gap..."*: that is 200 scroll events in 1 second. *" the mouse wheel isn't being scrolled during that time*": this can only mean that JavaScript cannot keep up with the event queue, whatever the dev tools say.

Comment: This is also known as "debouncing" the function call. See also https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Answer (score -1):

Posting here to include an image

setTimeout(func, 0) is not a guarantee that your code will run, at the 0s second, if there are already events lined up in the task queue(most likely triggered by scrolling) then they will have to finish being put in the execution stack and run.

check this image from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

[image: event loop and task queue]

If you need immediate execution, you need to make sure no event is being added in the task queue in the time you are scrolling the page, meaning no eventListeners like `.on('scroll', func)` or do the setTimeout before registering a func on `.on('scroll')`

Comment: I can very much understand that it is not guaranteed to run at 0 seconds, but I would hope that it would run much sooner than the 1.2 seconds later than it takes.

I've added an image to the original post that shows a timeline of the events happening.  I've added console output to mark the timeline with the time of when we execute the setTimeout call and when we get the callback.  In this example, it took over 1.4 seconds.

The summary graph also shows we are idle for most of the time we are waiting for the callback.  So, could it really be another event blocking us?

Comment: I don't know why I got down voted but you asked "Could a small stream of mouse wheel events that get executed very quickly delay the callback's invocation?" The answer is most likely yes, depending on what callback on the onscroll is doing